# Which of these is a better network project?

Tags: networking

I need to do a group project for network class. Here's what I'm thinking of.

1. Create a client that can communicate over facebook chat and do other stuff with facebook.
2. Put a program on a router to make it do something other than what it was originally intended to do.

I want to do a project that is interesting, impressive to the professor, and will teach me something. Which of these is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sound more like a programming class than a networking class. ;)

So, for a networking-programming class, I'd say the second option would be best.  The first would be coding against existing APIs; you'd likely be using an XMPP library, unless you implemented that yourself.  But unless you implemented the TCP stack yourself, you're really not getting into the realm that a networking class would be involved in.